# The name 'Item' does not exist in the current context out of foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to add link for print page, but i have error in code **The name 'Item' does not exist in the current context**

Inside of the foreach statement everithing is ok, but at bottom of page i need to add Image and link to Print page, included ID

Here is code of View:

```
**<a href = "/rezervacii/RelEDPrint?id=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem  => modelItem.relID)"><img src = "~/Content/images/print_icon.png" alt = "Печати" /></a>**
```

How to solve this?

**EDIT:** Answer is Here, i solved with this simple code.

```
   @foreach (var item in Model.Take(1))
  {

    <a href="/rezervacii/RelEDPrint?id=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tbl_relacii.relID)"><img src="~/Content/images/print_icon.png" alt="Print" /></a>

  }
```

Comment: change `DisplayFor(modelItem => ..` to `Display(item => ... )`

Comment: copy & paste my answer from below it works. Thanks @JoeDie

Answer (score 1):

Add this code line inside the foreach loop.

```
    @{ counter=0; }
    foreach()
    {
       if(counter==0)
        {
    <a href = "/rezervacii/RelEDPrint?id=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.tbl_relacii.relID[0])">< img src = "~/Content/images/print_icon.png" alt = "Print" /></a>
        }
 }
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

you dont need `@Html.DisplayFor` to display `id` you can do it directly by

```
<a href = "/rezervacii/RelEDPrint?id=@item.tbl_relacii.relID">< img src = "~/Content/images/print_icon.png" alt = "Print" /></a>
```

**Edit**

you can use this to get single id from `IEnumerable`

```
@Model.Select(x => x.tbl_relacii.relID).Single();
```

so your code will be

```
 <a href = "/rezervacii/RelEDPrint?id=@Model.Select(x => x.tbl_relacii.relID).Single()">
```

Comment: I tried this but i have error again **The name 'Item' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: @JoeDie it is because you are using it outside the loop can you share the full page ? it would be easy to answer

Comment: @JoeDie are you sending IEnumerable<tbl_rezervacii> in second page?

Comment: Yes it is IENumerable

Comment: @JoeDie check my answer and let me know if its working

Comment: I tried, but not work @Usman

Comment: @JoeDie you can check now it will work i have updated my answer again

Comment: Not work, i have error with { barracs

Comment: i solved the problem. Thank you  @Usman for your answers and comments.

Comment: @JoeDie can you tell how you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

replace item with modelItem that's the name you declared it with.

Comment: I tried it but Not Work :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple code of answer:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Take(1))
  {

    <a href="/rezervacii/RelEDPrint?id=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tbl_relacii.relID)"><img src="~/Content/images/print_icon.png" alt="Print" /></a>

  }
```